# Time complexity of determining the transitive reflexive closure of a graph

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory, graph-theory, transitive-closure

Consider an arbitrary directed graph `G` (that can contain self-loops) and `A` its respective adjacency matrix.
Is there a way (an algorithm) to calculate the adjacency matrix respective to the transitive reflexive closure of the graph `G` in a `O(n^4)` time? is there a way to calculate it in `O(log(n)n^3)`?
The transitive reflexive closure is defined by:

> Gt(V,E) is a the transitive reflexive closure of G: (u,v) are in E only if u = v or the is a path from u to v in G.

Answer (score 4):

This is known as the [directed graph reachability problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reachability). You want an *n*-by-*n* matrix with 1 if there is a directed path from one vertex to another, or 0 otherwise; or your purpose might be equally served by any other data structure which permits queries in O(1) time.

For directed graphs, the standard solution is to run some [all-pairs shortest paths](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest_path_problem#All-pairs_shortest_paths) algorithm such as [Floyd–Warshall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd%E2%80%93Warshall_algorithm) in O(*n*<sup>3</sup>) time, or [BFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) from all nodes in O(*n*<sup>2</sup> + *nm*) time, where *m* is the number of edges. Since you don't need *shortest* paths, [DFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) from all nodes is just as good as BFS.

Another solution is to do O(log *n*) matrix multiplications of the graph's adjacency matrix A, after first filling the diagonal with 1s, to find the matrix power A<sup>*n*</sup>. The running time of this will depend on the running time of your matrix multiplication algorithm. Asymptotically, the [current-best matrix multiplication algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication#Complexity) runs in about O(*n*<sup>2.373</sup>) time, so this gives a solution in O(*n*<sup>2.373</sup> log *n*) time. The matrix multiplication algorithm for transitive closures was shown by [Fischer & Mayer (1971)](https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1446319) to be asymptotically optimal, with the caveat that we don't know what the true complexity of matrix multiplication is.

These algorithms can be improved in most practical applications by first finding the [strongly-connected components](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strongly_connected_component) of the graph, and then just solving the reachability problem between the components. However, the worst-case running times will be the same since there could be up to *n* components anyway.

There are special-case algorithms for certain classes of directed graphs, such as [Thorup's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reachability#Thorup's_Algorithm) which solves the reachability problem for [planar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planar_Graph) directed graphs in O(*n* log *n*) time, or [Kamada's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reachability#Kameda's_Algorithm) which runs in O(*n*) time on a specific class of planar [directed acyclic graphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph).

For undirected graphs, a [union-find data structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure) can be built in O(*m* α(*n*)) time, where α is the very-slowly-growing [inverse Ackermann function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ackermann_function#Inverse).

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what @Kaya3 mentioned, [Purdom's algorithm](https://algowiki-project.org/en/Purdom's_algorithm) computes the transitive closure of a DAG in O(||+||), where ≤|| is the number of strongly connected components of the graph. Since ||=O(||^2), Purdom's runtime is O(||^2).

Comment: I think the complexity analysis on the page you linked is wrong. In step 3, you iterate over the edges in the reduced acyclic graph, and thus step 3 has complexity O(EV) where E and V are the number of edges and vertices in the reduced graph. Since in the worst case, every node is an SCC, this leads to O(EV) overall complexity.